# how to solve The requested URL /b.php was not found on this server. www.likjafh.net?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security

can anyone explain why this is happen?

how to solve The requested URL /b.php was not found on this server. www.likjafh.net ?

which kind of website  www.likjafh.net is ?

***www.likjafh.net is not my website , and i don't know anything about that***

There is no b.php in my server and i didn't write code that include or redirect to b.php in my WordPress site . How to solve this . when i google this question i have found so many website that effected the same problem (https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=The+requested+URL+/b.php+was+not+found+on+this+server.+www.likjafh.net&start=0).If any one know how to solve this please help . I think it may be problem in .htaccess file. But didn't know how to solve this .

Comment: Have you scan your site using malware finder tool? Do that please first. Looks malware there in some files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wordpress site. So may be this issue due to 
one of these plugin . Just uninstall and see the result

Google Analytics Dashboard for WP

or

Google XML Sitemaps (http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jpeg-upload-only)

also read

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-sketchy-redirects

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/danger-hazard-risk

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'm assuming you own or run www.likjafh.net.  (I'm not visiting it cause the URL looks pretty scary)

If you're getting the error in your log files, and is the result of an external client requesting that URL, there isn't anything you can do.  Except if you want it gone, just create an empty /b.php file that does a header("Location: /") to redirect the user to your home page.

If you're seeing it dumped out in the contents of your page output, then you'll need to dig until you find the offending code.  Start by turning off all plugins, and if the problem goes away, you've got a bad plugin.  Eliminate them via trial and error until you find the one that's causing the content being dumped.

This could also be malware that has infected your wordpress installation, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my site and resolved it by updating the GA plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after reading up on some posts, I de-activated the "Google Analytics Dashboard for Wordpress" plugin - which immediately resolved the error we were getting on our website.

I then deleted the plugin altogether for fear that it may be have or may be a sketchy plugin.

I do not know what, how, or why...but I just wanted to post here what resolved our problem.

Summary:

When vistors landed on our website which is a Wordpress site, there would be some error text on top that says "The requested URL /b.php was not found on this server." along with some other script-like text.

De-activating and removing the plugin called "Google Analytics Dashboard for Wordpress" solved the problem immediately.

I hope this helps anyone else that may be experiencing the same thing.